# Automatic Styling/Tinting of NSToolbarItem

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

Is there a way to tell OS X to automatically style/tint a `NSToolbarItem`?

I've added an "Image Toolbar Item" via IB/Xcode and set the icon to a black PDF [as described in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000967-TPXREF102).

However, my result does not resemble that of, for instance, the App Store:

[image]

I'm looking for something akin to what the TabBar in iOS does by default.

I'm new to OS X development... So any guidance would be appriciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Images need to be made template'd in order to get the correct styling (such as the engraved & blue styling).

This can be done in code with `-[NSImage setTemplate:]` *or* by having your image names end with "Template" (requiring no code changes).

---

To get the blue styling specifically, you have to set a borderless NSButton as the custom view of the toolbar item (rather than it being a standard item). That button has to have a type that results in it showing its state (e.g. a Round-Textured Toggle button), and when it has an On state, it will get then blue styling.

Comment: Used NSButtons just as you suggested - Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! I was trying to replicate Xcode's show/hide Project Navigator/Utilities etc. and this did the trick.

Comment: Selecting "Template" in the Render pull down by itself does nothing; the image name indeed needs to end in "Template".

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to create a tinted toolbar item in code, This is how I did it. Create the correct type of button `NSButtonTypeToggle` then set the buttons properties, then add the button to the toolbar item's custom view and finally the toolbar item is returned.

```
- (NSToolbarItem *)toolbar:(NSToolbar *)toolbar itemForItemIdentifier:(NSToolbarItemIdentifier)itemIdentifier willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:(BOOL)flag {

    // create toolbar items
    NSToolbarItem *toolbarItem = [[NSToolbarItem alloc] initWithItemIdentifier:itemIdentifier];
    toolbarItem.label = @"title";
    NSImage *iconImage = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameColumnViewTemplate];
    NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 40.0, 40.0)];
    button.title = @"";
    button.image = iconImage;
    [button setButtonType:NSButtonTypeToggle];
    button.bezelStyle = NSBezelStyleTexturedRounded;
    button.action = @selector(toggleColumnView:);
    [toolbarItem setView:button];
    return toolbarItem; 
}
```