# How to make a NSToolbar item toggle state

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an NSToolbar with NSToolbarItem instances. One of the toolbar buttons is in one of two modes, depending on whether it currently operating (has been clicked) or not. I am handling this in code by changing the icon for the button to have a background rectangle when the command it represents is operational, but I can't help thinking there must be another way.

I've tried using the Selectable checkbox in XCode Interface Builder attribute inspector, and it sort of gives the result I want, except when it is selected I can't click any of the other toolbar items. I also can't see how to deselect it.

I'm a bit of a Cocoa noob so I expect the two state toggle thing is just waiting for me to find it, except so far I haven't been able to.

This seems like it would be a common thing to want to do, thing is how?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24619943/233944)

Comment: I already use a templated image to provide a custom colour. I was thinking of looking at combining the image with a background rectangle myself but was hoping there was something available out of the box.

Comment: Ok, but you specifically asked about implementing a 2-state toggle. As per that answer, you can use a toggle button as a custom view for your toolbar item. Set the image and alternate image, and they will automatically toggle with the button state.

Comment: If you just want to get the "selected" appearance, out-of-the-box there isn't anything that will help you. An NSToolbarItem appearing "selected" in that way is not what one usually expects, so Cocoa won't give you anything for free there